# wx - how to create two notebooks side by side with different sizes?

Tags: wxwidgets, sizer, wxformbuilder

I want to create a window with two notebooks. The left one should be always as narrow as possible. The right one should be as wide as possible and expand when the window is resized. Is it doable in Wx?

This is what I managed to get done in wxFormBuilder. Both notebooks always have the same widths when I resize the window.
[image]

I tried changing the sizerItem proportion of each of them, but that obviously only changes the proportion. I want to only allow the right one to expand. Changing the wxEXPAND flag of each notebook only changes the vertical expansion and not horizontal.

Thanks for help.

Generated code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version 3.10.1-0-g8feb16b)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO *NOT* EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class MyFrame1
###########################################################################

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
                wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

                self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

                bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

                self.m_notebook1 = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                self.m_notebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel1, u"a page", False )
                self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                self.m_notebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, u"a page", False )

                bSizer1.Add( self.m_notebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

                self.m_notebook2 = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_panel3 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel3, u"a page", False )
                self.m_panel4 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel4, u"a page", False )

                bSizer1.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


                self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
                self.Layout()

                self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        def __del__( self ):
                pass
```

Comment: can you post the code you have?

Comment: Added, though I don't think it will reveal much. wxFormBuilder to me always had a very realistic preview.

Comment: Take a look at the "stretch" option and also try specifying max size for the left notebook.

Comment: YES! The maximum width option does stop the left notebook from expanding. I only wonder how "portable" this is across different resolutions and what if I add labels dynamically to the notebook. I think I'll have to find a formula for a usable max width.

Comment: @filo, that is why you don't set the position/size but let sizers do it for you.

Comment: @filo, you could also try to build wxPython based on wxWidgets master and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the proportion of the left item to 0 (which is the default) and of the right item to 1, which will allow it to expand to fill all the available space. It's as simple as this and it doesn't matter at all that the windows are notebooks -- the rules are the same for all windows.